# Gaming on 13.04 using more advanced drivers for Intel 3000 HD lagging?

Tags: graphics, 13.04, games, intel

I recently found a beta version of portal for steam. I install the beta version and started  it up to find the graphics didn't look right at all. I looked through the comments from OmgUbuntu seeing that they were talking about drivers for other graphics cards. Someone had an image of the same issue I have with the beta version of Portal. One other person gave 2 links to more updated drivers for Intel.  The first one was 12.04 and 12.10.

[Graphics drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers)

The second link was for 12.04 through 13.04 and is the one I used.

[launchpad archives](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)

I installed the packages, started portal again and this time it actually worked to make the grapics look right. I tried it with Team fortress 2 and that also worked since TF2 also didn't look right. However, when playing Bastion, the game is actually slower and lagging with these packages where as the default drivers worked fine for Bastion. So what are my options then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic options right now, neither of which your going to like. Your using non-mainstream drivers with a beta game.

You should probably log a bug/issue with valve so they know about the issue in their beta. Then I would *consider* downgrading your drivers to main steam and waiting for the new drivers to be included in the repos. There is a reason there not in your main repos yet, and this could very well be one of them. Specially if your pulling from xorg-edgers.

Comment: I know it's not the "loved" answer but it is the most correct one. You need to get feedback to the developers of each the game and the driver so they can address it.